# startActivity creating new instance of Activity every time

Tags: android, android-activity

I am calling startActivity to pass data from one activity to another using an activity's context in an external class.

This is one example of how I create the intent to be sent:

```
public static Intent createSearchIntent(Context context, Class<?> cls) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_SEARCH, null, context, cls);
    return i;
}
```

This is how the I start an activity:

```
mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I was mistaken in what happens. The activity is not destroyed when I call startActivity, however the activity I am sending the intent to always has it's onCreate method called so I am guessing that a new instance of the activity is being created instead of returning to the paused/stopped one.

How would I be able to change it so that I can just return to the paused/stopped Activity?

Comment: It shouldn't end your activity at all unless the system is low on resources. Please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: How can you say your activity is destroyed? did you see stacktrace in logcat for that activity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is when you need to use flags. For making a previously started activity to come back to the top of the stack you need to add the `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);` flag to your intent and then start that activity-`startActivity(i)` with 'i' being the intent name.
For a list of other flags have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29).

Answer (score 4):

Calling Activity B from Activity A doesn't by default does not destroy Activity A itself, what you see is Activity B displayed over Activity A, screen-overlapping. You can check by pressing `Back` button.

It's the Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I changed my question to reflect this.